# Trying to use Rundeck with tmux or screen for using ssh-agent

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tmux

I spend some time for setting up Rundeck tool - seems to be very usefull to use it as web interface to my shell scripts over few different servers. The thing is - you cannot simply use commands like tmux or screen -r to connect to any sesssion.

Why I need it? Because my shell scripts sometimes needs ssh keys with passwords, so my plan was to set up tmux or screen sessions with ssh-agent, join them and run scripts. But it does not work. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that one, maybe it will help someone else.
On the remote host I set tmux session, then run ssh-agent, ssh-add.
From Rundeck I simply run command `tmux send -t tabname ./script.sh ENTER`